Analysing Weekly Data from a single large duration record
I am working with a data table in Power BI.
I have a table of absence records where a person has a long absence ie Start Date: 01 May 2024 to End Date: 30 June 2024 Duration: 61 days (these are field in my table).
I want to analyse all table records by week but for a record like the long absence example above the whole 61 days is added to the week of the Start Date and not spread out.
For my analysis I would want the 61 days split between the 9 weeks that they belong to so when I add them to a visualisation with a weekly time on the x-axis they show evenly in the relevant week.

Hi can you provide example you tried measures tables etc.. ? This is not ChatGPT this is stack overflow.
